# How to modify default install directory for rpmbuild command?

Tags: linux, rpm, suse, rpmbuild

On `Suse Linux Enterprise Server 11`, I use `rpmbuild` to install a source rpm:

```
linux-a21w:/usr/src/packages/SPECS # rpmbuild -v -bi zlib.spec
```

By default, it installs into `/var/tmp/zlib-1.2.7-build` directory.In `zlib` source code directory, execute `make install`command:

```
linux-a21w:/usr/src/packages/BUILD/zlib-1.2.7 # make install
cp libz.a /usr/local/lib
chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libz.a
cp libz.so.1.2.7 /usr/local/lib
chmod 755 /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7
cp zlib.3 /usr/local/share/man/man3
chmod 644 /usr/local/share/man/man3/zlib.3
cp zlib.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
cp zlib.h zconf.h /usr/local/include
chmod 644 /usr/local/include/zlib.h /usr/local/include/zconf.h
```

Is there any method can pass arguments to `rpmbuild` command to make the header files and libraries to be installed to specified directories, such ad `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/include`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the point wrong.  You want to install in a temp dir to make the RPM.  You then install the RPM to get the final destination right.

The temp dir (known as BuildRoot: in your spec file) is just a staging area.  you install to here, almost like a chroot area.  THen you package your RPM with rpmbuild -bb, to make your RPM, then install as root.